# How to load EC private key from a Java string?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, private-key

I have an EC private key stored in Java String. I am using the following code to read the string and convert it into PrivateKey object which I need to generate a SHA256withECDSA signature.

```
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMKeyConverter;

public static PrivateKey getPrivateKey()  {
        try {
            Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
            Reader rdr = new StringReader("-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
                    "<line1>\n" +
                    "<line2>\n" +
                    "<line3>\n" +
                    "-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----\n");
            Object parsed = new PEMParser(rdr).readObject();
            KeyPair pair = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().getKeyPair((org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMKeyPair) parsed);
            return pair.getPrivate();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("IOException generating private key {} ", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I am able to generate a PrivateKey successfully using a unit test in IntelliJ. However, when I deploy my war on Tomcat, this code throws following exception :
*class "org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPublicKey"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package*

Maven dependency tree output:

```
 mvn dependency:tree | grep -i "bouncycastle"
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk15on:jar:1.49:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.49:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.49:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk15:jar:1.45:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15:jar:1.45:compile
```

I added one of the versions to pom exclusions. Still facing the same issue:

```
<exclusion>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
```

Any pointer is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Crypto providers like BouncyCastle are required to come as signed JAR file. Make sure you only use one version and that the JAR file is not modified by any packaging or deployment process.

Comment: you might have multiple versions of bouncycastle in your path. in case you use maven you can try ```mvn dependency:tree``` to double-check

Comment: @divadpoc : Thank you.  
I tried  mvn dependency:tree | grep -i "bouncycastle". 
Following is the output:

[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk15on:jar:1.49:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.49:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.49:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk15:jar:1.45:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15:jar:1.45:compile
How do I resolve this?

Comment: @divadpoc: I added 1.45 to pom exclusion. Still the same.
<exclusion>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15</artifactId>
      </exclusion>

Comment: just to be sure, as it's not obvious what library did cause the second import of bouncycastle, did you put the exclusion to the correct library, the library that is including your duplicate dependency ?
can you update your snippets with the information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally excluding unwanted version from war packaging resolved the issue. Added 'packagingExcludes' in my pom.

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <packagingExcludes>
              WEB-INF/lib/bcmail-jdk15-1.45.jar,
              WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk15-1.45.jar
            </packagingExcludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Ref : https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html